# Python - create blacklist file of IP addresses that have more than 5 failed login attempts in the authlog

Tags: python, ip-address, syslog, blacklist

Basically I have an authlog/syslog file with a list of log in attempts and IP addresses - I need to make a Python program that will create a txt file with all the IP addresses that have more than 5 failed login attempts - a sort of "blacklist".

So basically something like:

if "uniqueipaddress" and "authentication failure" appear more than 5 times, add uniqueipaddress to txt file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - please try and make it simple as I am very, very inexperienced in programming in Python! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For each line:

- read the IP and attempt status
- keep a dictionary by IP of amount of failed attempts

Then go over the dictionary:

- print to file all IPs with 5 or more attempts

---

Python hints:

- To read a file line by line: `for line in open(filename)`
- Parsing the log line depends entirely on its format. Some useful Python tools are the `split` method of a string, and regular expressions
- Keep a dictionary, i.e. `ips[ip]` is amount of attempts

Comment: Thank you, that helps - any chance of any example code to show this in practice? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do something similar to what you're looking for.  It's not perfect, but it's a good jumping off point.

```
ips = {}
for line in open('your_log.txt'):
    parts = line.split(' ') #assuming this is a good place to split
    if parts[1] == "AuthenticationFailure":
        if parts[0] in ips:
            ips[parts[0]] += 1
        else:
            ips[parts[0]] = 0

for ip in [k for k,v in ips.iteritems() if v >= 5]:
    #WRITE TO FILE HERE
```

This assumes that your log file is structured something like so:

```
1.1.1.1 LoginSuccess
2.2.2.2 LoginSuccess
3.3.3.3 AuthenticationFailure
```